# jQuery Cookie: How prevent adding dot "." in the beginning of domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a problem. I need to set the domain for cookie without `.` in the beginning. I set options for cookie like this:

```
cookieOptions:{
    expires:30,
    path:'/',
    domain:document.domain,
    secure:false
},
```

and

```
$.cookie("searchQuery", cookieObj, this.cookieOptions);
```

Can I customize jQuery options?

Comment: *"Can I customize jQuery options?"* ... Yes, of course you can. What is the value of `domain`? It should not start with a period anyway (domains never start with a period).

Comment: I know i'm being silly in suggesting this, but you could use substring :P    (".domain").substring(1)

Comment: do you mean [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location) object? there is also a property `window.location.hostname`.